# How to create pagination with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a html table which data are from a MySql database , got by using PHP. If there are many rows returned from the database then I want to show only 10 rows in the table and at the bottom of it there are numbers indicating a page-like indicator ( like when we google ). So how to achieve this pagination with JQuery ?

Comment: This question is way too open ended. Have you tried breaking your problem up? First achieve pagination on the server side, then start putting UI components in.

Comment: In regard to the performance, i have to second Johns statement. Depending on the size of the fetched data, this is growing out of hand in older/slower browsers, since you would have to fetch ALL data and split it into pages afterwards, always carrying all data with you. You should split the php request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do the pagination **in** jQuery, since pagination's objective is to prevent fetching data you don't need. There's plenty of answers in Google, but the way I've done it in the client side is using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/).

As for the server side pagination, PHP would get the number of items to fetch and the *index* of the starting item as parameters, then you would query the database with something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename LIMIT startingIndex, itemsToFetch;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) would help